# Flask - error binding parameter 0

Tags: python, flask

First of all, my forms are not populated correctly using forge_factory. I have some classes I call in the form using query_factory. When Flask loads this template, it does not loads the parameters that I saved.

**views.py**

```
@tasks.route('/edit/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit(task_id):
  """ Edit task """
  task = Task.query.filter_by(id=task_id).first_or_404()
  form = TaskForm(obj=task, next=request.args.get('next'))

  if form.validate_on_submit():
      form.populate_obj(task)

      db.session.add(task)
      db.session.commit()

      flash('Task updated', 'success')

  return render_template('tasks/edit.html', task=task, form=form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Task(db.Model):

  __tablename__ = 'Tasks'

  id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(db.String(120))
  asset_id = Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Assets.id'))
  asset = db.relationship("Asset", uselist=False, backref="task")
  task_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('task_types.id'))
  task_type = db.relationship("TaskType", uselist=False, backref="task")
  task_status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('task_statuses.id'))
  task_status = db.relationship("TaskStatus", uselist=False, backref="task")
  progress = Column(db.Float)
  assigned_to_id = Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
  assigned_to = db.relationship("User", uselist=False, backref="task")
  description = Column(db.Text())
  start = Column(db.DateTime(), default=get_current_time)
  due = Column(db.DateTime(), default=get_current_time)
  task_closed = Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class TaskForm(Form):
  next = HiddenField()
  name = TextField(u'Task Name', [Required()])
  asset_id = QuerySelectField(u'Asset',
            query_factory=asset_query,
            get_pk=lambda a: a.id,
            get_label=lambda a: a.name,
            allow_blank=False)
  type_id = QuerySelectField(u'Type',
            query_factory=type_query,
            get_pk=lambda a: a.id,
            get_label=lambda a: a.name,
            allow_blank=False)
  status_id = QuerySelectField(u'Status',
            query_factory=status_query,
            get_pk=lambda a: a.id,
            get_label=lambda a: a.name,
            allow_blank=False)
  user_id = QuerySelectField(u'Assigned To',
            query_factory=user_query,
            get_pk=lambda a: a.id,
            get_label=lambda a: a.name,
            allow_blank=False)
  start = DateField(u'Start Time', format='%m/%d/%Y')
  due = DateField(u'Due Time', format='%m/%d/%Y')
  description = TextAreaField(u'Description', [Required()])
  submit = SubmitField('Add Task')
```

I got error when I try to save changes in Task:

```
InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. u'UPDATE "Tasks" SET asset_id=?, start=?, due=? WHERE "Tasks".id = ?' (<pursue.assets.models.Asset object at 0x10ebde050>, '2014-11-28 00:00:00.000000', '2014-11-28 00:00:00.000000', 1)
```

Comment: Did you mean to ask an actual question? If you are getting an error, please include the *full traceback*.

Comment: Yeah, I've updated code with traceback.